# How can I color weekend instead of hide in full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

Currently I am using FullCalendar plugin for my project. There is an event name 'weekends'. If weekends set as false then sunday and saturday will hide.

But I want that the background color of weekend will be specified instead of hide it.

Here is the js code in plugin that I find out.

```
    if (this.opt('weekends') === false)
    {
       hiddenDays.push(0, 6); // 0=sunday, 6=saturday
       // $('.fc-fri').css('background', 'green');
       // alert($('.fc-fri').css('background'));

        //$('table.calendar > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(-n+2)').addClass('fc-fri').css('background', 'green');
        //$('.fc-sat').css('background-color', '#00FF00');
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (
            !(isHiddenDayHash[i] = $.inArray(i, hiddenDays) !== -1)
        ) {
            dayCnt++;
        }
    }

    if (!dayCnt) {
        throw 'invalid hiddenDays'; // all days were hidden? bad.
    }

    this.isHiddenDayHash = isHiddenDayHash;
}
```

Through the commented code I tried to color weekend days. But I have found no result. If there is any suggestion please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CSS

```
.fc-sat, .fc-sun {
background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: I already tried it. But the problem is that Sometimes weekend can be different. I actually want to set it dynamically. Through an ajax call I get a result which indicates that which day will considered as week end. If I set this code in fullcalendar.css then always specific week days is colored. I want to set it dynamically.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".fc-weekend-column").each(function(i,el){
       $(this).css("background-color", "#FFF7F7");
    });

Comment: dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent) {
    var checkDay = new Date($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    if (checkDay.getDay() == 6 || checkDay.getDay() == 0) alert('Weekend!');
}

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly

You can use a css rules like

```
.fc-sat, .fc-sun {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

one more way, you can check if the selected date is a week end, and act as you want. You can use the dayClick (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) event in this way:

```
dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent) {
    var checkDay = new Date($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
    if (checkDay.getDay() == 6 || checkDay.getDay() == 0) alert('Weekend!');
}
```